# Powershell - Populate list of AD users in large security group that are in a particular OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get an AD Security Group down to a manageable size, but due to display limits in Powershell, this is proving difficult for me. The group is down to 47,720 now after removing all disabled AD accounts. Now I'm trying to filter it down to Enabled users that live in this particular OU. Below is what I've used with success in the console.

```
Get-ADGroup "very_large_secgroup" -properties Member | Select-Object -expandproperty member | get-aduser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=PurgeStudents,OU=DisabledAccounts,DC=contoso,DC=com" | Select-Object SamAccountName,DistinguishedName
```

When I try to count this, or pipe it via Out-File though, I get:

> get-aduser : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that
>   take pipeline input.
>   At line:1 char:92
>   + ... ty member | get-aduser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=PurgeStudents,OU=Dis ...

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, as I am a novice in Powershell magic.

Comment: The reason you see this error is because you are piping into `Get-ADUser` without using the `-Identity` parameter. `-Identity` is what accepts pipeline input by value. When you use `-Filter`, you are selecting a parameter set that does not include `-Identity`.

Comment: So because I have get-aduser pulling from the already established list of group members, it doesn't matter when I just receive console output. When I try to pipe the entire thing into a csv, it starts to break down?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. But you cannot use the syntax `$listOfUsers | get-aduser -filter * -searchbase OU`. `-Filter` and `-SearchBase` have to be left off if you are piping a list of values into `Get-ADUser` as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `-Filter *`, you could filter for all previous retrieved users. And there is a cmdlet to get the members of a group:

```bsh
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "very_large_secgroup" -Recursive | Foreach-Object {Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like $_.Name" -SearchBase "OU=PurgeStudents,OU=DisabledAccounts,DC=contoso,DC=com" | Select-Object -Properties SamAccountName, DistinguishedName}
```